# rake causes compilation of assets using production.rb in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am upgrading to `rails 7.0.3.1` from `rails 6.1.6.1`. Whenever I run a rake task there is an exception generated.  For example with this simple rake task

```
namespace :tests do
  task temp: :environment do
    puts "Environment is #{Rails.env}"
  end
end
```

if I run `rake tests:temp` then I see the following

```
Precompiling assets for local
precompile asset_host is 
rake aborted!
KeyError: key not found: "APPLICATION_HOST"
/Users/myname/myapp/config/environments/production.rb:8:in `fetch'
...
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[master c970ac9] Add precompiled assets for local
2 files changed, 1593 insertions(+), 1840 deletions(-)
...
Environment is development
```

I can provide the full trace if requested.  Note that after the exception, the rake test does work successfully.  Also the code is making a git commit to the effect `Add precompiled assets for local`.  The environment variable `APPLICATION_HOST` is not set in the development environment, because it is only needed in production.

I was not seeing this problem in rails 6. What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have a method defined in a Mixin which looks like this

```
def precompile_assets(target: 'local)
  puts "Precompiling assets for #{target}"
  ...
  system("RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_HOST_PATH=#{asset_host} rake assets:precompile")
end
```

This was only meant to be used in rake tasks used for deployment. It looks like somewhere in Rails 7 there is another method with the same name, which is being overwritten.  The quick solution is rename the method so it does not clash. The longer solution is refactor so as it is not a Mixin.

I guess all those articles about the dangers of Mixins were right.